# Typical power limit of zener in integrated IC input protections

Tags: integrated-circuit, protection

I am using NCP1031 as a first stage voltage regulator IC in a PCB.

Here is the block diagram of the regulator:
[image]

And here is the link to its datasheet for easy access:
[NCP1031 datasheet](https://pt.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/NCP1030_D-2316946.pdf)

There were a lot of PCBs produced already and we have noticed only now that the voltage divider that we use for detecting Under-Voltage (UV) was dimensioned in a way that makes UV go above the 10V reverse voltage of the integrated Zener diode. My calculations give a Zener dissipation of 1.5mW at the worst scenario possible, but in the real world, it should be closer to 0.5mW.

I have searched the datasheet of this IC and did not find a power rating for these integrated Zeners and I am currently facing the hard decision of manually replacing or not the resistors in the voltage divider of UV on 2000+ boards.

I know power rating depends on temperature, surface area and types of materials involved. I'm seeing that 0201 SMD resistors are rated for 50mW, but I have no idea of the size of these integrated Zeners. If I say they are a hundred times smaller than 0201 SMD resistors, they will have a surface area that is 10000 times smaller and let's say the specific thermal conductivity is 100 times higher since it's a solid and not air... I'm looking at a power value of 0.5mW so it might be ok but I have no idea how off my guesstimations might be. Some help?

Comment: IC designer here: I do not think that the 1.5 mW will be an issue. Although these zeners will indeed be small, they are very likely there for ESD protection. That means that from an IC design perspective: they're still relatively large devices so they will be able to handle a small amount of power. If you would exceed 50 mW then I would be worried. But 1.5 mW is really not much. Also note that the max power rating of the IC is more than 500 mW, so again, 1.5 mW is peanuts.

Comment: Do a test only for this specification (input UV with equivalent resistor, current, voltage) and measure temperature with IR camera if you own one. As stated before, not really a problem.

Comment: I'd replace them with better suited resistor values.

Answer (score 0):

Datasheet absolute maximum ratings for the chip say 10V, which means anything above that may damage the device, and if any of the limits are exceeded, device functionality should not be assumed, damage may occur and reliability may be affected.

Basically, the voltage should never be allowed to go beyond 10V or the device can be damaged.

Usually, a manufacturer also mentions a nominal operating range where the operation is guaranteed, but this does not. In those cases, going outside nominal operating range means the chip won't be damaged but it does not have to work either.